# Having a PCIe device driver handle different interrupts in the same IRQ line from same FPGA device

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, fpga, pci, pci-e

i don't know if i'm doing the right question here (mainly because i'm not that good at understanding the problem i'm in right now).

Currently i have a FPGA using Legaxy Interrupts (INTx, mainly because the team developing the FPGA code still doesn't know how to work with MSI/MSI-X).

In the first iteration of my development, i used the uio_pci_generic device driver to read the interrupts generated by the FPGA device.

But now, i will have at least 8 different Interrupts signals that will be sent by the FPGA, each one of them using the same IRQ line (INTa,...). The objective is to have the user-space applications open the device, wait for an interrupt and then read which interrupt source from the same IRQ line was sent. Is this possible?

I tried to create 8 different minors to that same uio_pci_generic driver, but i can't see the interrupts, the system shuts down.

What would be the ideal course of action to develop this device driver? Can i still use the same UIO driver? Or will i need to use the PCI methods to register the devices and so on?

As you can see, i don't have all the experience needed to develop this more complex code. I don't even know if i asked the right questions.

Thank you

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but tell your hardware guys that MSI interrupts are simply a 32-bit write with a special  address and data that are supplied by software. (Hardware doesn’t even have to worry about whether the addesss and data are correct; that is totally software’s problem.) MSI interrupts are actually simpler than INTx, because the hardware doesn’t have to send deassert messages and keep track of whether the interrupt is asserted.

Comment: Yes. I understand what you're saying. But they don't have the human resources to change that in this iteration of the project. For now is trying this and after this is done, maybe going the other way with MSI. Thanks for the reply. And what you said about the assert and deassert was one of the things that made my mind race. Mainly because i'm new here and i had to deal with those things when trying to learn what the code inside the linux kernel does.

Comment: If I understand your setup correctly, the interrupts are not distinguishable at the hardware level. Right? Then they cannot at the software level. What is typically done in this cases is to have a register with the interrupt source (anything would do) and block/delay all interrupts until the software writes to this register.

Comment: The FPGA will have 8+ interrupt sources. They'll be connected to an OR Gate. As i understood, only the conection between the FPGA will be a single connection. The same for all interrupts. I guess whenever the CPU detects an interrupt it will have to analyze some kind of register into the FPGA memory to verify which interrupt source it is and then use the corresponding read() from the device driver.